# Finding memory allocation of Ruby Arrays

Tags: ruby, memory-size

I wanted to find out the memory consumed (in bytes) by data types. I called `size` method on an integer. Since I am running a 64 bit machine, it returned 8.

```
1.size # => 8
```

Similarly, for strings and arrays, it returned 1 byte per character/integer.

```
'a'.size # => 1
['a'].size # => 1
['a', 1].size # => 2
```

1. Why is there no size method for float?
2. Shouldn't heterogeneous arrays like `['a', 1]` return `1 + 8 = 9 bytes` (1 for char, 8 for integer)?
3. Is it correct to call `size` to check memory allocated to ruby data types?

Comment: in the case of an array, the size method is just an alias for the length method of the array (which is just the number of elements in the array). similarly, in the case of strings, the size method is just the character length of the string.

Comment: In the title, you indicate that array does not have `size`. In the text, you indicate that float does not have it. It is not clear what you mean.

Comment: `'€π'.size` returns `2`; so `.size` counts the number of *characters* in strings, not *bytes*.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking for MRI memory usage. Ruby has [**`ObjectSpace`**](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/objspace/rdoc/ObjectSpace.html) : The objspace library extends the ObjectSpace module and adds several methods to get internal statistic information about object/memory management.

> You need to require 'objspace' to use this extension module.

Here is what you will get:

```
 > require 'objspace'
 => true 
 > ObjectSpace.memsize_of(Array)
 => 5096 
 > ObjectSpace.memsize_of(Hash)
 => 3304 
 > ObjectSpace.memsize_of(String)
 => 6344 
 > ObjectSpace.memsize_of(Integer)
 => 1768
```

**Note:**
Generally, you **SHOULD NOT** use this library if you do not know about the MRI implementation. Mainly, this library is for (memory) profiler developers and MRI developers who need to know about MRI memory usage.

Comment: From the documentation of this method: *Note that the return size is incomplete. You need to deal with this information as only a HINT. Especially, the size of T_DATA may not be correct.*

Comment: @spickermann: Yes you are right. Actually I never need to use of this in my development. As OP has asked so I was also eager to know and got this solution.

Comment: Also note that the example here actually get the size the of *classes* themselves, not of an instance. `ObjectSpace.memsize_of([])` usually returns 40 on ruby 2.2+ for example, which is the size of the empty array in memory (also the minimum size of most ruby objects)

Answer (score 4):

These are two different methods that serves different purpose for two different data types.

In eg 1, you are applying `size` to fixnum. This method:

```
Returns the number of bytes in the machine representation of fix.
```

source: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-size

However when used with array, `size` is alias for `length`. Here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-size. Which:

```
Returns the number of elements in self. May be zero.
```

Answer (score 2):

`Array#size` returns the count of elements of the `Array` rather than memory allocated.